# How to select the last part of a string with VBa?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to name a text file created by my code.

the text file is a formated version of another text file.
Let's say i have file A: original file, and file B: formated file.
file B is created by my VBa code and i want to name file B : formate + "file A"

here's my code:

```
Dim order As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim Folder_path As String
Dim lastrow As Long

Dim fSo As Object
Dim myFile As Object
MsgBox InStrRev(Sheets(8).Cells(6, 12).Value, "\")
FolderName = "Formated Files"
Filename = "formated " & Right(Sheets(8).Cells(6, 12).Value, InStrRev(Sheets(8).Cells(6, 12).Value, "\")

[...]

 Folder_path = FL + "\" + FolderName

Set fSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fSo.FolderExists(Folder_path) Then
    fSo.CreateFolder (Folder_path)
    If fSo.FolderExists(Folder_path) Then
        Set fSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set myFile = fSo.CreateTextFile(Folder_path + "\" + Filename, True)

        myFile.WriteLine "Error"

        myFile.Close
        Set fSo = Nothing
    End If
Else
    If fSo.FolderExists(Folder_path) Then
    Set fSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myFile = fSo.CreateTextFile(Folder_path + "\" + Filename, True)
```

for now i'm trying to get the name of the file B by using the path of the file A (so i need to get the last part of the path witch is the name of file A) and adding "formated" to it.

If you see a better way to get that name or if you find a way to simplify my code feel free to help.

Comment: fso has (eg) `GetBaseName` and `GetExtensionName` methods which you can use here.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getbasename-method

Comment: There's no need to keep creating a new fso - just do it once then use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your filename looks something like this:

`C:/documents/docs/filename.txt`

And you want to append a word before the .txt:

`C:/documents/docs/filename_suffix.txt`

the easiest way is probably:

`newfilename = Replace(filename,".txt","_suffix.txt",,,1)`

---

However, if you wanted to append a word ***before*** the start of the file's name:

`C:/documents/docs/prefix_filename.txt`

then you could use FSO's GetBaseName in a replace

```
filebase=fso.getbasename(filename) & "."
newfilename = Replace(filename,filebase,"prefix_" & filebase,,,1)
```

Comment: does it work if file name looks like this: C:/documents/docs/filename.txt